# Why is Logcat showing "E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: reg_info"?

Tags: android, mysql

I changed the database version, added the appropriate amount of spaces to the SQL function to create a table and updated the parameters for the function that inserts input into the database, but LogCat still displays:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: reg_info
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting user_password=e user_email=e user_name=e
While compiling: INSERT INTO reg_info(user_password,user_email,user_name)
```

I condensed the information displayed from the errors just to focus on these specific errors. This problem occurs on the emulator and Android devices. Thank you.

This is my contract class where I declared all the columns for my table:

```
package com.example.xxx.datadigger;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class TableData
{
    public TableData()
    {

    }
    public static abstract class TableInfo implements BaseColumns
    {
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME="user_info";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME="reg_info";
        public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
        public static final String USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";
        public static final String USER_CON = "user_con";
        public static final String USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    }
}
```

Here is where I attempt to create a table and insert data insert:

```
package com.example.xxx.datadigger;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TabWidget;


public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
     public static final int database_version = 2;
     private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
     private static final String COMMA_SEP = ", ";
     private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "
                + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + TableData.TableInfo.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + "); ";

    public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
        super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "Database created");
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {

        sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("database Operations","Table created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name,String password,String email)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME,name);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD, password);
        //cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_CON,con_password);
        SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("database Operations","One raw inserted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [onUpgrade()](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int))(After version number increased) method is empty so if your table was not created during [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase))(First time DB gets created) it will never be created and same error will be thrown. 
As you are saying that you created space then increased version and then trying will never workout.

Try uninstalling the app and re-inistall in you existing code.

Comment: Simplest way go to the settings then click on app then uninstall it or by using command adb uninstall package_name

Answer (score 0):

So you're updating from version 1 to version 2 of the database? If yes, then you need to run the create statement for your new table "reg_info" in onUpgrade. This method is called when the database is updated to a newer version (so your version 2). OnCreate is only called when the database doesn't exist yet, or you call it explicitly.

The purpose behind onUpgrade is to allow you the developer to update the database scheme while preserving data thats already in it. So your onUpgrade might look like:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
}
```

If you want to force the database to recreate itself and call onCreate, then wipe the app settings and open your app again, it should wipe the db and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

On Updating database version you need to overwrite onUpgrade method like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");

    onCreate(db);

}
```

Then reinstall the app