# com.example.f_a_11_8_2019 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i can't use my database in emulator, it shows this line

> com.example.f_a_11_8_2019 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

and this

> com.example.f_a_11_8_2019 E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: word
>
> com.example.f_a_11_8_2019 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: word (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT KAZAKH FROM word WHERE TURKISH = ?

Comment: I hope it'ill help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31652133